# Count of Rows colored in SSRS Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, colors, count, reportbuilder3.0

I am trying to calculate the Count rows of particular colored Rows .For example

The background colors are coming from an Expression which is a condition based

So I am trying count how many are green color and How many are red color from  the data

Location  Amount

Usa      100---Green color Background

UK       200--Red Color Background

India    3000---Green color background

---

Total Green Rows --- 2

---

Looking for help

Thanks

Comment: More info required. How are the background colors set? Assuming there is an expression to set them, it is that expression that you need to do the count over.

Comment: Correct .Background colors are done by expression .Now looking for How many Green counts and how many red counts .

Comment: You must have a logic to calculate the background color.. why not just count whatever logic it that you are using with a countif ??

Comment: @PAVAN  That's what myself an Harry are saying. You need to count where your 'green' expression is 'true' for example. Edit your question and add more info. And you might consider marking some of your previous questions as answered, none of them, are marked as answered but I can see a few that appear to answer your question exactly.

Comment: Sure as per your comments I have updated the Question also

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUM with the same conditions combined with an Iif expression returning 1 when your expression is true.

Your expression will look like the one below

```
=Sum( Iif( condition for green rows, 1, 0) )
```

Comment: Sorry It is not working . As i am using column grouping any changes need to be done ? or any where the logic need to be changed

Comment: And for Normal Total of counts i.e .Count(Fileds) generally refers  to total count .But when i am extracting the total counts ,(0 related cells /rows ) are getting ignored . for example 1,0,2,4,5 = Total count should be 5 ,but 0 related cells are getting ignored and showing only 4 .Looking for help

Comment: Please provide more info like the expression you are using, sample data, layout etc in order to improve my answer